# How to distribute MongoDB test data over VCS?

Tags: python, mongodb, mercurial, dvcs, nosql

I'm working on a Python/MongoDB project in both my computer at home and my laptop.
The schema in document stores, naturally, is best represented by the data itself - and that's why I want to distribute my test data over Mercurial, together with the code itself.

Would the best way be to **simply dump the BSONs in a file and add it to the mercurial repository?**

Comment: Maybe try to run it through an `xxd` filter in each direction, if you think it will be more meaningful to be able to diff it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumping BSON and putting it into a VCS would not make much sense, since it's binary file and can't be viewed easily.

You can export a collection to a JSON, by using `mongoexport` tool. You can even pass it a query filter to limit number of exported documents.

Here's an example (reformatted for readability):

```
sergio@soviet-russia$ mongoexport -d test -c geo \
sergio@soviet-russia$    -q '{"_id":  ObjectId("4efa5f7d8840e680c850cd94") }'
connected to: 127.0.0.1
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4efa5f7d8840e680c850cd94" }, 
  "longg" : [ { "start" : 322815488, "end" : 322817535 }, 
              { "start" : 822815488, "end" : 822817535 } ], 
  "m" : "Cracow", 
  "postal" : 55050, 
  "lat" : [ "XX.89XXX", "XX.74XXX" ] }
exported 1 records
```